# How to exclude deprecation messages from logs in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, monolog, deprecation-warning

I have migrated an application from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4.4.

Now I have a lot of deprecations for each request/ Sf command (I can't fix that deprecations).

How can I exclude deprecations from the log for this Symfony App?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Exclude the `php` channel from the log handler:

Eg. `config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
            formatter: monolog.formatter.session_request
            channels:
             -  '!php' # <----------- add this line
```

Leave deprecation messages in the `dev` mode though. You should be aware of the changes in upstream packages.

PS. in newer Symfony versions you have to exclude the `deprecation` channel instead, i.e.:

```
channels:
    - '!deprecation'
```

Comment: Hmm, I have tried this, but it's not working. It just keeps adding `php.INFO: User Deprecated:`

Comment: This is a working example. I use it myself in many projects. Fix your config, clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks for responding. You are correct. There was a completely different issue at hand that prevented my changes from taking effect.

Comment: This will exclude _all_ levels of messages in the php channel. Ideally, it'd just exclude those of level INFO.

Answer (score 10):

What works for me in Symfony 6.1.X, is setting it the `deprecation` channel and type to `"null"`. This will make sure the deprecation messages will not show up in the logging *but* still be available to see from the debug toolbar.

```yaml
# config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml
monolog:
  channels:
    - deprecation
  handlers:
    deprecation:
      type: "null"
      channels: [deprecation]
```

Answer (score 3):

Work for me **Symfony 5.4+**

add in channels list 'deprecation', and use in handles argument '!deprecation'

its work filter example:

```
monolog:
    channels:
        - 'deprecation'
    handlers:
        main:
            type: rotating_file
            max_files: 30
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: debug
            channels: ['!event', '!doctrine', '!deprecation']
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the following env variable (eg. in .env.local):

```
SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=weak
```

Comment: Before saying it does not work (i was about to do it) search this env var in all the dot env files

Answer (score 0):

The error handlers are controlled by [`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/DebugHandlersListener.php) Error levels that should be logged are defined by the constructor argument `$levels = \E_ALL` which is by default `E_ALL`. Unfortunately the value is static in the [service definition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/debug_prod.xml). But you can override it by a compiler pass and introduce a parameter `php_log_level`:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace YourBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class PhpErrorLevelCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if(! $container->hasDefinition('debug.debug_handlers_listener') || ! $container->hasParameter('php_log_level')) {
            return;
        }
        $container
            ->findDefinition('debug.debug_handlers_listener')
            ->replaceArgument(
                2,
                (int) $container->getParameter('php_log_level')
            );
    }
}
```

This compiler pass is registered in your bundle:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace YourBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use YourBundle\DependencyInjection\PhpErrorLevelCompilerPass;

class YourBundle extends Bundle {

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new PhpErrorLevelCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

In your parameters file you can then set the value to `E_ALL & ~ E_DEPRECATED & ~ E_USER_DEPRECATED` which is `8191`:

```
php_log_level: 8191
```

Note that this applies for Symfony 3.4 and 4.4.